# What's a -CLASSIFIED no. 2-?

Tags: luftrausers

Luftrausers is a fast-playing, fast-dying game of aerial combat. There's a series of missions to carry out, all focused on reducing various enemies into debris, in increasingly creative and difficult ways. Eventually, you get a mission to kill a -CLASSIFIED no. 1-, which ends up being kind of like an Ace enemy, except they fire lasers. (And Aces are already fairly hard to kill!)

I killed the -CLASSIFIED no. 1-. Now I have a mission to kill a -CLASSIFIED no. 2-. What on earth is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having finished the mission, I can say that a -CLASSIFIED no. 2- is simply an improved submarine, with a couple of battleship-like cannons installed. If you've reached the mission to kill one, you've probably already seen them around. Those cannons fire constantly, but they don't seem to aim much – they just sweep back and forth, filling the sky with flak (somewhat like the blimp). A little further research gives two more facts:

1. They'll only show up after you kill at least one regaular sub, and
2. Once you've killed a regular sub, they show up about 33% of the time that a submarine would spawn.

If you feel like modifying the game, you can tweak this value at `<your_Steam_directory>/SteamApps/Common/Luftrausers/data/res/spawncoordinator.json`.

Much like normal submarines, the -CLASSIFIED no. 2s- are fairly hard to kill because they spend so little time above water; it's hard to do enough damage in the short time it's in play. Personally, I killed mine in the usual least-effort way: the Nuke plane chassis.

(On a bit of a tangent, I cheated to make the super-sub appear, by adding "Submarine" once to every line in `spawncoordinator.json`. For some reason, this made a large number of Aces show up. Perhaps the game has a limit on the number of subs in play at any given time, and falls back to Aces when it isn't allowed to spawn a sub?)